# Scalability in Angular bindings using a Model class

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, binding

I'm new to Angular and finding a salable and modular way to populate set of derived variables in a Class.

```
export class Calculator {
    constructor(
        public x?: number,
        public y?: number,
        public total?: number,
    ) {
        this.total = this.x + this.y;
    }
}
```

What I'm supposed to happen is, Angular should know there is a dependency between `total`  and `x`,`y`. Whenever `x` or `y` is updated, Angular should re-evaluate the `total`.

I know that this can be done by writing,

```
this.calculator.total = this.calculator.x + this.calculator.y
```

in `ngOnInit` of controller or in a `onchange` trigger. But it is not scalable and modular if I have lot of derived variables. It's true that Class is only typescript and it doesn't know about Angular. Can you help me by putting alternatives.

Comment: why not use a getter for total?

Comment: so you want to detect the changes of x and y. if changes is detected then implement the addition am i correct?

Comment: @YashRami yes. correct. But not in explicit way by telling specifically look for x and y. It is not scalable

Comment: got it let me write a answer :)

Comment: @k0hamed if i had a getter called `total`, will angular re-evaluate field `{{ calculator.total }}` in template when x or y is chnaged?

Comment: @TRiNE yeah, the change detector will recompute it whenever it detects any change

Comment: @k0hamed no, angular is not updating `{{ calculator.total }}`. may be angular doesn't know any relation between `x`, `y` to the `total`

Comment: @TRiNE can you insert the code in which it doesn't update? as if it doesn't update it may mean angular didn't detect a change at all. I tried a simple example to make sure and it worked normally.

Comment: @k0hamed yes using a getter works. but it does the calculation for every change (not only for x and y). but looks it is only the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not efficient to use a getter for total
You can update the `Calculator` class to be something like

```
export class Calculator {
    constructor(
        private _x?: number,
        private _y?: number,
        public total?: number,
    ) {
        this.total = this.x + this.y;
    }
    private update() {
        this.total = this.x + this.y;
    }
    set x(val) {
        this._x = val;
        this.update();
    }
    set y(val) {
        this._y = val;
        this.update();
    }
}
```

now you can have multiple properties recalculated whenever a change happen within the object.

Comment: Very good design. really this didn't came in to my mind. Thank you.

Comment: But need to be careful when saving and retrieving the model objects (stores as JSON). Then getter and setters will loose. `Object.setPrototypeOf` saved me